# How to do Unit Test with Dependency Injection .net Core 2

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

I start to develop a new web application, I create a Domain Object, Inteface, DAL and BLL...

I would like to test all before use that.

If I use the developed function in web application in .net core 2 I put in Startup.cs some code like this :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            **services.AddTransient<ITableOfTableRepository, DBTableOfTableRepository>();**

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        }
```

And in my Controller add this code

```
 public class TablesController : Controller
    {

        private readonly ITableOfTableRepository _repository;

        public TablesController(ITableOfTableRepository repository)

        {

            this._repository = repository;

        }
```

How to do a UnitTest project for testing all before of the use in web application?

How to use dependency Injection in unit test?

BR

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: I understood his question and am here looking for the same thing. Essential, we need to know how access/activate/play the role of the DI framework that .Net Core is playing when instantiating a service. You write some code to start you app. You writesome code in the ctor of the controller. And in between, "magic" happens.

That's great, unless you want to instantiate a controller inside a unit test in a unit test project. There is no context, no HTTP context, no access to the DI framework that I can find. So, I can't instantiate a controller to test it.

That is the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to develop in a test first approach...

You will pass by several steps:

1. Your test is not compiling because you need to write a controller action and create an interface
2. Once you created an interface you could mock/stub it (using framework like [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) or others) and inject when you create the controller

   var userService = Substitute.For();

   ...

   var controller = new MyController(userService)
3. you write the controller code for your test to pass